On the polynomials $\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}k^m q^k$
A sequence of polynomials
$$P_0(q),\ P_1(q),\ P_2(q),\ \ldots$$
with real coefficients is called $q$-log-convex if for each $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ every coefficient of the polynomial $P_{n+1}(q)P_{n-1}(q)-P_n(q)^2$ in $q$ is nonnegative.
Observe that $$\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}k=\binom{2n+1}{n+1}$$
by the Chu-Vandermonde identity. Motivated by this, for $m,n\in\mathbb N=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}$ we introduce the polynomial
$$S^m_n(q):=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n+k}k^mq^k.$$
Based on my computation via Mathematica, I have formulated the following conjecture.
Conjecture. For any integer $m\ge2$, the polynomial sequence $(S^m_n(q))_{n\ge0}$ is $q$-log-convex.
We know that there are lots of studies on log-convexity of integer sequences and $q$-log-convexity of polynomial sequences.
QUESTION. Does the above conjecture hold? Can one prove it via the known methods?
Your comments are welcome!

Is "conconvex" a typo?

Yes, that's a typo. I have corrected it.

Recall that those numbers $f_n=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk^3\ (n\in\mathbb N)$ are called Franel numbers. Define $f_n(q)=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom nk^3 q^k$ for $n\in\mathbb N$. I also conjecture that the polynomial sequence $(f_n(q))_{n\ge8}$ is $q$-log-convex.
